# How to keep English as default input language?

Tags: windows-10, ime, language-bar

I originally had Windows 7 English version. I had enabled both Microsoft Japanese IME, as well as Google Japanese Input.

I upgraded to 10, then from then on in startup, Default text input would be switched to Japanese, then after April Update it was working as intended, now again it happens.

So how do I change order, switch to, keep English as default input language in input indicator from startup by default?

It's very annoying to manually change, I want to keep original English input by default in IME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to **Settings > Time & language > Region & language**.
At languages, normally you see a list of all the languages your Windows version is configured in.

Changing your default option there should normally resolve your problem. You can simply press **Set as default** for English.

Comment: Not display language, only IME. OS is English version, I have not installed Japanese UI, Language Pack, with Japanese, Google, Microsoft IME installed, used  from past Windows 7

Comment: sorry, misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes, I'd mentioned Input in question

Comment: The answer seems correct. This part might be missing: In Region & language, click on English, then on the up-arrow until it is the first language.

Comment: @harrymc for IME?

Comment: This determines the first language in the language bar. Or is your problem different?

Comment: I'm using April Update.I don't see any input option in region & language window i.imgur.com/LbBIBqO.jpg